# Intercepting a URL to get Auth Code?

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, httprequest

I am trying to send an image from my android application to a secured storage facility provided by a vendor. This facility uses oAuth 2.0.

The guy who has been helping me has told me that my app needs to launch their login screen from my app and then when the user logs in they will be took to the redirect URL that I specified which will have the Authorization code in it.

His instruction to me was that my app needs to "intercept this" in order to retrieve the authorization code.

This is all quite new to me and I am unsure what this means or how to achieve this?

Can anyone offer me help?

Comment: Yeah but I don't know the authorization code to send with the request

Comment: which tool  is using for image uploading

Comment: Kiteworks Storage

Comment: I mean which network call  using ex. Volley,Retrofit or etc.

Comment: oh httpurlconnection

Comment: I had updated my answer with authorization  please refer this

Answer (score 0):

Follow This step

1) Stroe redirect URL

2) Get Authorization code from redirect URL

3) pass Authorization code in your image uploading request as a **header** as below

```
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization Code", code);
    con.setReadTimeout(15000);
    con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    con.setDoOutput(false);
```

Comment: yes I know how to send headers with request. My problem is I am trying to extract the auth code from the redirect url once I log in

Comment: can your redirect URL past here

Comment: this url is asking about id password

Comment: yeah the user must log in to get to it

Answer (score 0):

If he has his own Auth server which he is providing to you then you must have to use their UI login screen to pass any parameters. Another way is use "ACCOUNT KIT (by facebook)" and "Firebase Auth (by Google)".
You can search on them first and see either they are fruitful for your requirement or not.
I am currently working on both and they are much better than any other Auth services.

Comment: Yeah I have their login screen comes up then the user signs in. it is just after they have signed in im not sure how to get the auth code from that or to even return to my app from the browser